# Django doesn't accept image submission, method and enctype included in form tag but browser console claims it is missing

Tags: html, django, web, post

I'm following along with a tutorial to build a Django project. Part of the project is being able to upload an image to the test cdn directory. This is what my form looks like currently:

```
<form method='POST' action="." enctype='multipart/form-data'> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

The method and enctype are very clearly defined.

I've also set up my settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOCAL_STATIC_CDN_PATH = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn_test')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(LOCAL_STATIC_CDN_PATH, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
]
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(LOCAL_STATIC_CDN_PATH, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

set up the files to be received in the view:

```
form = BlogPostModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
```

set up the model use ImageField:

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='image/', blank=True, null=True)
```

and the url patterns:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
# test mode
from django.conf.urls.static import static
# display images/files saved in the test cdn
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

But even with all this, the console informs me:

Form contains a file input, but is missing method=POST and enctype=multipart/form-data on the form.  The file will not be sent.

This is the tutorial in case it helps https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oQvMHpKkms&list=PLM39hJgCef42hVok8ZRRE4LpLD-5bOxBh&index=20&t=13385s the part in question starts at 3:48:00.

Comment: Are you sure you only have one `<form>` tag in the template? Use your browser's "View Source" function to make sure.

Comment: No there is only one <form> tag. Interestingly, though, the browser, FireFox, doesn't show the enctype in the View Source. Only the method and action.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. You must be looking at the wrong template while Django uses another (obsolete?) one.

Comment: I've checked, no other templates it could be checking from the path I've set. Also the data that isn't the image actually gets uploaded from the form.